# Как сделать чтобы анимация была определенного кол-во пикселя, а не пол экрана?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть слово, и при анимации оно идет от самого левого конца экрана и только после этого встает в середину, смотрится так себе если честно. Как сделать чтобы анимация начиналась например 200 пикселей от середины?

```
<h1 class="lr">LR UDBE 999</h1>
```

```
.lr {
    font-family: 'Rowdies-Light', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    animation: poyavleniye 1s ease-out 1;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял вы используете keyframes-анимации. Возможно в начале анимации вам нужно сделать положение элемента на 50% от центра, а потом поместить в середину.

```
@keyframes poyavleniye {
    from {
        margin-right: 200px;
    }

    to {
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.lr {
    font-family: 'Rowdies-Light', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    animation: poyavleniye 1s ease-out 1;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Выровните блок по центру при помощи записи

```css
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Далее через `@keyframes` задайте стартовое значение трансформации со сдвигом, через функцию [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc()), до исходного состояния.

```css
@keyframes name {
  from {
    transform: translate(calc(-50% - 200px), -50%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.lr {
  font-family: 'Rowdies-Light', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  animation: poyavleniye 1s ease-out 1;
  color: red;
  
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes poyavleniye {
  from {
    transform: translate(calc(-50% - 200px), -50%);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 class="lr">LR UDBE 999</h1>
</section>
```

---

Или упрощённый вариант

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.lr {
  font-family: 'Rowdies-Light', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  animation: poyavleniye 1s ease-out 1 reverse;
  color: red;
  
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes poyavleniye {
  to {
    transform: translate(calc(-50% - 200px), -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 class="lr">LR UDBE 999</h1>
</section>
```